# Como retornar um valor selecionado em um select?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho esta caixa de seleção:

```
<select id="valores_confinamento" class ="form-control">
    <option  value="ceu" >Ceu aberto</option>
    <option value="galpao" selected>Galpão fechado</option>
</select>
```

E gostaria que quando selecionado fosse possível alterar o valor em:

```
<div style="top: 95%; left: 34%;position: absolute">
     <span id="id_area_piquete_por_animais" ></span>
</div>
```

Eu fiz:

```
var selection = document.getElementById("valores_confinamento");
var selected = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].text;
function valor(){
    if (selected =="ceu" ){
        document.getElementById("id_area_piquete_por_animais").innerHTML=10;
    }
    if (selected =="galpao" ){
        document.getElementById("id_area_piquete_por_animais").innerHTML=20;
    }
}
valor();
selection.addEventListener("keyup",valor);
selected .addEventListener("keyup",valor);
```

Mas não retorna o algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro se o que quer exibir é o valor ou texto da opção. De qualquer forma criei um *snippet* com os dois valores. Se quiser obter o valor da opção seleciona, use `this.value`. Se quiser obter o texto dentro da `<option>` use a forma que está fazendo.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('valores_confinamento'),
    output = document.getElementById('id_area_piquete_por_animais');

select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  output.textContent =  'Valor: '    + this.value +
                        ' / Texto: ' + select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
});
```

```html
<select id="valores_confinamento" class="form-control">
  <option value="ceu">Ceu aberto</option>
  <option value="galpao" selected>Galpão fechado</option>
</select>

<div style="top: 95%; left: 34%;position: absolute">
  <span id="id_area_piquete_por_animais"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Renan, justamente isso o que queria!

Comment: marquei, valeu mesmo!